# Python Sklearn with tree - Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am working with load_iris data set, but I have obtained an error with input variables.

I imported the dataset, and selected X and y:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris  
iris = load_iris()

x = iris.data

y = iris.target
```

Then I splitted my data in train and test data:

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.5, train_size=0.5, random_state=1)
```

And finally trained my data with the desired model:

```
tree = DecisionTreeClassifier()

tree.fit(x, y)
```

After that, I make a prediction and I try to obtain the accuracy score:

```
training_prediction = tree.predict(x)
 
print('Accuracy training set: ', accuracy_score(y_true=y_train, y_pred=training_prediction))
```

When I launch this final code I obtain the next Value error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-586-d8aab911a5f5> in <module>()
----> 1 print('Accuracy training set: ', accuracy_score(y_true=y_train, y_pred=training_prediction))

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_consistent_length(*arrays)
    210     if len(uniques) > 1:
    211         raise ValueError("Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of"
--> 212                          " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
    213 
    214 

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [75, 150]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a large explanation in order you can understand how to solve this kind of problems and be able to do it by your own next time.

The error says you are having a problem with inconsistent number of samples when launching the function `accuracy_score`. So let's focus on this function. It concretely says that your `y_true` has 75 samples and your `y_pred` has 150 and the function can not deal with this discrepance.

You are trying to obtain the "Accuracy of the training set" as you said. So the accuracy_score has to compare the **true** y_train and the **predicted** y_train. The first input is correct: y_true= y_train, but the second not. To obtain the training_prediction you did `tree.predict(x)`. This code will predict all the samples x! **And you only want to predict the train samples, so you must use x_train**.

To correct just update the code below:

```
training_prediction = tree.predict(x_train) #we changed x by x_train
```

This should solve your problem.